# Jquery Fullcalendar shows event in week on wrong (first) day. Dayview and month are ok

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Month view is perfect. Day view is fine too!
But switching to week-view shows event on the first day of the week.
Changing columnFormat, timeFormat or firstDay does not fix problem.

Answer (score 0):

hey, sounds like a bug. could you post this to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list) and *please* include a working example that demonstrates the bug (a runnable html file, or a demo online). thank you!